# can’t run my flutter project on android device

Tags: flutter, flutter-android

i have project using flutter. why the project can’t run on android device?
initally installed but missing, I thought it would build itself as before. but it turns out an error like this:
[image]
what’s wrong?

Comment: More information on what you've tried so far would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
adb reboot
```

But for me I had to change my settings first:

Settings → Developer options → Root access

Make sure ADB has Root access: